How to prevent parent view animations from overriding that of a child view?
When the user presses the button to show the rectangle, the offset animation that of the text should not be overridden by the .smooth(duration: 0.25) but instead continue its 50 second linear animation.
Below is the full example.
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showingRect = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Show Rect") {
                withAnimation(.smooth(duration: 0.25)) {
                    showingRect.toggle()
                }
            }
            
            TextView()
            
            if showingRect {
                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundStyle(.blue)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            }
            
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct TextView: View {
    @State private var animate = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("This is a very long text. Yeah, it is very very long.")
            .lineLimit(1)
            .offset(x: animate ? -300 : 0)
            .onAppear {
                withAnimation(.linear(duration: 50)) {
                    animate = true
                }
            }
    }
}


Use .animation(nil, value: showingRect) on the TextView to say that when showingRect changes, TextView should not be animated.
TextView()
    .animation(nil, value: showingRect)

If you still want the text to be animated upwards to fit the new rectangle, add .geometryGroup:
TextView()
    .geometryGroup()


The text view won't animate to move and  fit in the incoming rectangle though.

Your solution works for iOS 17 and above but is there a solution to this for iOS 16?

@SwiftUIEnthusiast I think drawingGroup() works too, but it has other side effects that might be undesirable.

For my purposes,, drawingGroup works but what are the side effects I should take note of?

@SwiftUIEnthusiast The main one is that it clips the text at its bounds. Try running the app with a shorter text and compare. The effect is much more obvious with a shorter text. This can be somewhat mitigated with a .frame(maxWidth: .infinity) before drawingGroup().

Possible to explain why geometryGroup works in this case? Like what it’s trying to do behind the scenes? Apple docs are quite unclear

@SwiftUIEnthusiast The explanation in the docs is quite good IMO, but I'll try to explain it in my own words again. By default, SwiftUI propagates geometry-related animations (size & position changes) until it reaches a leaf view (Text in this case), But the Text is affected by .animation(nil, value: showingRect), which removes all the animations that are caused by changes in showingRect, so its position is not animated. By adding geometryGroup, we "stop" the propagation of the animation just before the animation is removed.

When using modifier geometryGroup() on TextView, we don't need to remove the animation explicitly anymore, i.e. we do not need modifier animation(nil, value: showingRect) anymore, don't we?

@CouchDeveloper Oh you're right. offset is also geometry-based.

Use the .transaction modifier to isolate the animations. Also use the .animation modifier to ensure the text offset animation continues while preventing the parent view's animation from interfering.
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showingRect = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Showing Rect") {
                withAnimation(.smooth(duration: 0.25)) {
                    showingRect.toggle()
                }
            }
            
            TextView()
            
            if showingRect {
                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundStyle(.blue)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct TextView: View {
    @State private var animate = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("This is a very long text. Yeah, it is very very long.")
            .lineLimit(1)
            .offset(x: animate ? -300 : 0)
            .animation(.linear(duration: 50), value: animate)
            .onAppear {
                animate = true
            }
    }
}


Let me know if this works!

I have changed the code, let me know if it works now...
